# server side control in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

can we use server side controls in MVC, if no then why server side control list appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the webforms viewengine (default) you can use the controls that doesn't use viewstate in asp.net mvc as well. And if you add a form with the attribute runat="server" you can use the controls that use viewstate as well. But I'd tell you not to use any of them even if you can. They don't really add any benefit for you anyway as you do not use your code-behind classes. You can't use them in the same way in your controller action.

Answer (score 0):

No, not really, as they all rely on ViewState and a lot of the web forms plumbing.  As to why they appear, I'd guess it's because you're on VS2008 and MS hadn't got a good way of telling one aspx page from another.